# <router-outlet> makes html content disappear in Angular

Tags: angular

I am not sure why `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` makes the content of `app.component.html` disappear. For example, since I do not have `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` in the below code everything is fine.

**`app.component.html`**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Abdulaziz</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#pics">Pictures</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="links.html">Links</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#articles">Articles</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <br> <br>

</div>
```

whenever I add `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` under the `</div>` the content disappear immediately. Note that this problem does not show up in another project I have.

Comment: do you see any error on console?

Comment: one reason might be there is error in console, so no rendering

Comment: yes there is an error. `'router-outlet' is not a known element`

Comment: do I need to do anything before I use `<router-outlet>` ?

Comment: yes, you need to define routes and import RouterModule. Checkout official guide: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Import RouterModule into your app.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Add RouterModule into your imports []

like this:

```
imports: [RouterModule]
```

if you have a separate routing Module, import it there and export it